# How to insert a plot into another plot

Tags: plotting

I would like to know whether there is a way to insert a plot into another plot.
I would like to do some plot from a function an then, inside this plot, in the right down corner add a smaller plot of the same function covering a smaller region.
I tried with Epilog but it's not possible that way, it gives me a fail

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've seen `Inset[]`?

Answer (score 27):

...or do it dynamically so you can position the inset where you like it:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]},

 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> {Dynamic[
     Locator[Dynamic[pt], 
      Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> White, 
       ImageSize -> 150]]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: 1+ I liked this Dynamic tip! Cool!

Comment: That is pretty nice, but is there a method by which you can read the coordinates after you are done with placing?

Comment: After running in version 12.1.1, your code outputs the following error message: "Raw object \!\(\*FormBox[\"x\", TraditionalForm]\) cannot be used as \
an iterator."

Comment: @Alittlemouseonthepampas if you change the 2 ```x```s in the second ```Plot``` function to anything else it works. So change the second ```Plot``` to ```Plot[Cos[y], {y, 0, 2 Pi}, Background -> White, ImageSize -> 150]```

Answer (score 25):

You can use `Inset` for this

**Building a new `Graphics`**

```
gr1 = Plot[Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 6 Pi}];
gr2 = Plot[Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, Pi}];

Graphics[{First[gr1], Inset[gr2, {15, -.6}, Automatic, Scaled[.4]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}, AbsoluteOptions[gr1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Using `Epilog`**

```
Plot[Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 6 Pi}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[gr2, {15, -.6}, Automatic, Scaled[.4]]}]
```

Comment: Ha Yep, question solved! That's what I was looking for!
And with Background->White option it covers the old plot if necessary!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: For some reason, this method doesn't work on Mathematica 10.0.1!

Comment: @Mahdi It works for me.

Comment: @halirutan: Probably related to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68937/more-ticksticks-errors-in-absoluteoptions-in-v10). I'm getting `Axes::axes: "{{False,False},{False,False}} is not a valid axis specification. "` and `Ticks::ticks: "{Automatic,Automatic} is not a valid tick specification."` using under Linux 64-bit.

Answer (score 16):

You mean something like this?

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}];
p2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π}];

Show[Graphics[{Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, p1], 
  Rectangle[{0.7, 0.4}, {1, 1}, p2]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This was how it was done before `Inset[]` came along...

Comment: @J.M. Ha, it means that it is a long time that I didn't have the need to do something like this.

Comment: (+1) very nice. I don't think i have seen this syntax before; any references?

Comment: @kguler, it was [documented in old versions](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/functions/Rectangle); apparently, when `Inset[]` became available in version 6, that piece of syntax was quietly redacted.

Comment: @J.M. thank you.

Comment: This is really helpful because `Inset[]` does not allow you to specify positions (at least I didn't figure out) in terms of the corners of the figure. It is difficult to know the center position but the end-points are easy to know.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to `Inset` etc., you can do this manually with the 2D Graphics editing tools.

First producing plots as halirutan did:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]
p2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Click the first one to select it (orange border):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then **Copy** or **Cut** the object.

Next, double-click the second graphic to enter editing mode (gray border):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And **Paste** the first graphic:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can then position and resize the inset graphic using the orange frame.
When you are done just click outside of the main gray frame.

Comment: Even easier, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a good solution, but in the end I would like to have a code from where I can re-run if I want those specifications again. Any simple way of retrieving that information?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão Sorry, I never saw your comment.  I can't think of anything practical but that could be a good question; why don't you post it?  (If you haven't done so already in the long time since you asked this.)

Comment: hahah I love this one because of the simplicity, though it won't show any useful technique  .