# How to insert a plot into another overlay plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to insert a plot into another overlay plot. Here is my code:

```
xy1 = Table[{i, 2*i}, {i, 1, 10}];
xy2 = Table[{i, i^2}, {i, 1, 10}];
xy3 = Table[{i, i^3}, {i, 1, 10}];
p1 = ListPlot[xy1, FrameLabel -> {"x", "2x"}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashed], Red}, 
   Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, ImagePadding -> 40, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Red, Automatic, Automatic}, 
   PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle]}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All];
p2 = ListPlot[xy2, FrameLabel -> {"x", "", "", "x^2"},  
   PlotStyle -> Blue, Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
   ImagePadding -> 40, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Blue}, 
   FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, All}, 
   PlotMarkers -> \[FilledUpTriangle], Joined -> True, 
   PlotRange -> All];
p3 = ListPlot[xy3, FrameLabel -> {"x", "x^3"},  PlotStyle -> Green, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, PlotMarkers -> \[EmptyCircle], 
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
p12 = Overlay[{p1, p2}]
p123 = Graphics[{p12, Inset[p3]}]
p1232 = Graphics[{Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}, p12], 
   Rectangle[{0.3, 0.25}, {0.9, 0.9}, p3]}]
p1233 = Graphics[{First[p12], 
   Inset[p3, {5, 20}, Automatic, Scaled[.8]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AbsoluteOptions[p12]]
```

p12 is the overlay plot of p1 and p2, having two y axes. I want to insert p3 into p12.

I have read this post: [How to insert a plot into another plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14556/how-to-insert-a-plot-into-another-plot)

And tried three ways to do the job, with the result figure represented as p123, p1232, and p1233 respectively. However, none of p123, p1232, and p1233 is successful:

p123:

[image]

p1232:

[image]

p1233:

[image]

Among them p123 and p1233 caused errors. P1232 is close to what I want, but still is very weird. I want to insert p3 into the blank area of p12. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Overlayed plots do not have a head `Graphics` they are an `OverlayBox` so this is why your code is failing. You can overlay more than two items so maybe that might be your best option.

Comment: So is it possible to get double y axes (with different ticks) without overlay?

Comment: Yes and you can search and find code for that but as shown in Kubas answer just put the inset in the relevant plot before you use overlay.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are couple of possibilities, for example:

- via `Overlay`:

  ```
  Overlay[{p1, p2, Item[Show[p3, ImageSize -> 120], Alignment -> {-.5, .5}]}]
  ```

  [image]
- via `Epilog`:

  ```
  Overlay[{p1, 
           Show[p2, Epilog -> {Inset[p3, Scaled[{.3, .7}], Center, Scaled@.5]}]
         }]
  ```

  [image]