# How to add a subplot in corner of plot?

Tags: plotting

How is something like the plot with subplot shown in this image achieved with Mathematica?

[image: subplot with subplot]

Comment: Look at `Inset` in the documentation...

Comment: [Closely related: How to insert a plot into another overlay plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37565/5478)

Comment: thanks, exactly what I was looking for.