# How to enlarge a specific part of a graph using Plot Command?

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

How to enlarge the closed curves of any `Graph` and `Show` them in a separate `Graph` within the same big `Graph`?  You can use any `Function` to `Plot` such type of `Graph`.`Just_like_the_following_Fig`.
[image: <code>this_Fig</code>]

Comment: Have you looked at [how-to-insert-a-plot-into-another-plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14556/how-to-insert-a-plot-into-another-plot)?

Comment: One of ways,

`p1 = Plot[x Sin[1/x], {x, -1/2, 1/2}, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
 ImageSize -> {500}, Frame -> True, Axes -> None]`


after that restrict the `PlotRange -> {{-0.02, 0.02}` as

`p2 = Plot[x Sin[1/x], {x, -1/2, 1/2}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.02, 0.02}, {-0.02, 0.02}} , PlotStyle -> {Red}]`

copy the p2 (by single click on it) and then double click on the p1, and paste p2 on it (p1).

Answer (score 3):

```
plot = 
  Plot[x Sin[1/x], {x, -1/2, 1/2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
    ImageSize -> {500}, 
    Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> None]
```

[image: plot without inset]

```
smallplot = 
  Plot[x Sin[1/x], {x, -1/10, 1/10}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.02, 0.02}, {-0.02, 0.02}} , 
    PlotStyle -> {Red},
    Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> None]
```

[image: zoomed plot with smaller domain]

Now you can combine these plot to make a final plot as follows

```
finalplot = 
  Plot[x Sin[1/x], {x, -1/2, 1/2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red},
    ImageSize -> {500}, 
    Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> None,
    Prolog ->Inset[smallplot, {0.0, .3}]]
```

[image: Combined plot]

I just showed how to combine two plots. You can play with plot and frame styles. To get "zoom-in' effect you need to plot the same function on a smaller domain, then combine them by using Prolog followed by Inset.