# Inset figures using show

Tags: plotting, inset

If I have to figure done as in the following format:

```
Figure1= Show[....(*Several figures*)....]
Figure2=Show[....(*Several figures*).....]
```

**Questions:**

1. How can I put `Figure2` as an inset of `Figure1`?
2. How can I specify the size and where `Figure2` will go in `Figure1`

I tried using the following but it plots both figures on top of each other (showing mostly `Figure1`):

```
Show[Figure1, Epilog -> {Inset[Figure2]}]
```

I also tried using what I found here: [How to insert a plot into another plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14556/how-to-insert-a-plot-into-another-plot) but it didn't work for me, perhaps because of `Show`?

Thanks,

Comment: Use `Show[Figure1, Graphics@Inset[Figure2, ....]]`

Comment: @MarcoB this seems to give the same result than `Show[Figure1, Epilog -> {Inset[Figure2]}]`. I guess it can work by reducing the size of `Figure2` but `ImageSize` is not suitable in this case. Also by using a command to place it in a given location

Comment: Not sure that I understand; I posted an example in the answer below. See if that clarifies what I meant. If that doesn't work, you might have to share the exact structure of the two Figures you have.

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for the clarification! it helped a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two sample graphics generated by combining plots with `Show`:

```
fig1 = Show[Plot[Style[Sin[x], Red], {x, -2, 2}], Plot[Style[Cos[x], Red], {x, -2, 2}]];
fig2 = Show[Plot[Style[x^2, Blue], {x, -2, 2}], Plot[Style[-x^2 + 2, Blue], {x, -2, 2}]];
```

Let's combine them by inlaying the second one into the first one, with control over size, relative position, and placement:

```
Show[
  fig1,
  Graphics@Inset[fig2, {-1.5, -0.3}, {Left, Bottom}, Scaled[1/3]]
]
```

[image: combined graphics]